# git cherry-pick list of commits from other branch

Tags: git

I often find myself merging stuff from alpha branch to main branch. The way I do this, is typically by creating a list of all commits on a specific branch (which is not yet merged to main branch).

```
 git log origin/release/some_alpha_branch..feature/anotherbranch --pretty=format:%h --no-merges --reverse > commits.txt
```

this gives me a list of commits, in reversed order, which I can manipulate in notepad++ in order to replace \n with spaces. After that, I have a list of commits divided by spaces which I can copy paste in my cherry pick command

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit <pasted-list-of-space-separated-commits>
```

Depending of the changes, I need to merge, commit, git cherry-pick --continue, and repeat.

Once done, I reset all the commits to create one commit with a decent commit message

```
git reset --soft head~<number-of-commits-I-created>
```

It's workable to say the least, but I was wondering if I am doing things "the wrong way".

Are there better approaches to achieve something similar with less actions?

Comment: Sounds like you reinvented `git rebase -i`.

Comment: ok, that means close to nothing to me. how can I use rebase to merge commits from one branch to another?

Comment: You are not merging by your own admission. You are **cherry-picking**.

Comment: @bas I don't see where you are merging here. You say "Depending of the changes, I need to merge". What do you mean by "merge"? Do you mean that after you execute the command `git cherry-pick --no-commit <pasted-list-of-space-separated-commits>` that there are conflicts that you have to resolve? This frequently happens with `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Code-Apprentice is saying, you should use `rebase -i` to spare you the trouble:

So, if you want to cherry-picks revision from X~10 up to X (both revisions included in the things you want to cherry-pick) you could do:

```
git rebase -i --onto whatever-branch X~11 X # you want to include X~10 so you use X~11 in the rebase
```

Then have fun with the editor (move revisions around, indicate different actions for each), save, exit and behold as rebase runs its magic. The only thing you need to be careful with is the revisions to start/end.... because if the *end* is a branch, it would be moved after the rebase... so you should consider always using revision IDs. Also, the base branch does not move so you might need to move that pointer too when you are done.